# yii2 show message from database error

Tags: yii2

I have related tables and show at gridview. When i want to delete data from gridview, i take the mysql error about this data using other tables field. At that time i want to show message to user for example "This data not deleting".

I did it at yii 1.1 as follows.

views/xxx/index.php

```
<div id="statusMsg">
    <?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('success')):?>
        <div class="flash-success" >
           <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('success'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('error')):?>
        <div class="flash-error">
          <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('error'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

gridview

```
array(
'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
'afterDelete'=>
        'function(link,success,data){ 
             if(success) $("#statusMsg").html(data); 
         }',
),
```

controller/xxxcontroller

```
public function actionDelete($id)

{
  try{
     $this->loadModel($id)->delete();
     if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
       Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success','Normal – Deleted Successfully');
     else
       echo "<div class='flash-success'>Yiyecek Başarıyla Silindi</div>";
  }catch(CDbException $e){

  if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error','Normal – error message');
  else
    echo "<div class='flash-error'>Yiyecek silinimedi.</div>"; //for ajax

  }
}
```

but afterDelete not using in yii2 . And i didn't know what to use instead of afterDelete.

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify which version of Yii you're using - you're referring to Yii2, but your code suggest Yii 1.1. And please fix your code samples - your `'` and `"` are incorrect, and non-existing indentation makes it unreadable.

Comment: I am fixed code samples. I give a code samples from yii 1.1. Same code not work for yii2. afterDelete property not defined in yii2. My question is how can i use this worked ( worked for yii1.1) code samples at yii2.

Answer (score 1):

I used following code in controller delete action

```
    $connection = Yii::$app->db;
    $transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();
        $transaction->commit();
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success','Silme işlemi başarılı.');
        return $this->redirect(['index']);

    } catch (IntegrityException $e) {
        $transaction->rollBack();
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error','Silme işleminde hata oluştu.');
        return $this->redirect(['index']);

    }catch (\Exception $e) {

        $transaction->rollBack();
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error','Silme işleminde hata oluştu.');
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
```